# Magento 2 REST API - Creating cart price rule is not working

Tags: magento2, rest-api, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm trying to create a cart price rule via REST API but always get error 400 Bad request with message: Specified request cannot be processed.

I even try to use minimum request body (only required fields) on a fresh Magento installation to ensure no extension causes the error but still no luck. There's no log in exception.log to investigate.

I still can use REST API for other things, just creating sale rule is not working.

Please anyone can tell me what am I doing wrong. Below is my request detail. My Magento version is 2.3.3. Thanks.

POST /rest/v1/salesRules

```
{
  "rule": {
    "name": "Test API",
    "website_ids": [
      1
    ],
    "customer_group_ids": [
      0,1,2,3
    ],
    "uses_per_customer": 0,
    "is_active": true,
    "stop_rules_processing": false,
    "is_advanced": true,
    "sort_order": 10,
    "discount_amount": 1000000,
    "discount_step": 1,
    "apply_to_shipping": false,
    "times_used": 0,
    "is_rss": true,
    "coupon_type": "NO_COUPON",
    "use_auto_generation": false,
    "uses_per_coupon": 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use the API now. The reason is I used **v1** in URL. When I change to **V1** (V in capital) it works.
Hope this help anyone with same issue.